# Consume java web service in Biztalk

Tags: web-services, biztalk

I have a reference to a web service written in java. I need to use it in my BizTalk project. So I add the reference via **Add Service Reference - Advanced - Add Web Reference** since java web service is not a WCF service. OK, VS generates for me XSDs and ODX for the service. But when I try to compile the project, I get very weird error *"Missing partial modifier on declaration of type XXX; another partial declaration of this type exists"*. The same error is described [here](http://www.biztalkgurus.com/biztalk_server/biztalk_2009/f/32/t/16965.aspx).

I thought that I'd missed something so I created a brand new solution, added there a Console Application, added the web reference and that solution builded successfully. Thus I can conclude that I get the error only if I add a web service reference in BizTalk solution.

I tried to fix the error manually, opened the *Reference.map.cs* file, added ".Biztalk" suffix to the generated namespace and everything compiled successfully. Is it really a bug in code generator for BizTalk project or am I missing something?

Comment: Have you tried creating a brand new **BizTalk** project and solution and add the web reference again?

Comment: @Fabio, of course I have. The same results. I suspected that Java web service was incorrectly implemented but after I'd created a console application I made a conlusion that it is biztalk code generator that fails to create right files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure, I have never seen that error...

However, what I would do is create a class library project and add the web reference here. You can then use this in the SOAP send port, as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa559642%28BTS.20%29.aspx) (see point #5). You can also reference the class library in your BizTalk project directly. Since you said that the web reference works in a Console application, perhaps this could work...

Also, you could use the XSD schemas directly - but this will require more work. You will have to promote a couple of properties manually in an orchestration or custom pipeline component. You can find more details on [this post](http://www.jonfancey.com/default.aspx?key=2006-11-08T20:48:14Z) (website is currently down, but hopefully will be back online eventually).

Finally, you could also try the WCF adapter, using the httpBinding. That's designed for interop and should work as long as you have the schemas to define the messages.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you. Finally I got it working. What I did is the following: using **Add Web Reference** wizard I have generated code that cannot be compiled due to the namespace issue. Then I deleted all files but the service xsd one. Then I added an orchestration using **Add New Item** and created a new port type in it. After that I set up my orchestration to use the port type I'd defined and created input and output messages of the types which are defined in the service xsd file and are required by the port type. Then I set up a send port using **BizTalk Server Administration** and finally it worked.